# Will I have to re-install ubuntu when 18.04 is officially released?

Tags: 18.04

I recently purchased a new laptop, and I decided to take the plunge and get Ubuntu 18.04, despite it still being in beta. While there have been a few minor quirks here and there, for the most part it's worked fine for me, and I'm pretty happy for it.

When ubuntu 18.04 is officially released on April 26th, will I have to download it onto a bootable thumb drive and update that way, or will my version be equivalent to the full version as long as I continue to regularly install updates?

In summary, **What is the correct way to update from a beta version once the full version has been released?**

Comment: just do normal upgrades and your beta will become (or more accurately remain) official18.04.

Comment: To complement @guiverc answer be prepared to do a lot of updates given recent bug history since Jan 4/2018.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the beta of Ubuntu 18.04 but I'm pretty sure you could just run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` as usual. I don't see any reason why you would have to reinstall.

4/10/2018: Edited to include `sudo apt-get update`. Thanks to WinEunuuchs2Unix for pointing this out to me!

Comment: it is generally recommended to do `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get upgrade` from what I've read.